# Replace a Pandas subrow with an array of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a (simple?) problem, but that cannot understand how to solve in a pandas way.

I have this CSV:

```
,Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 1,1Me,2Gi,3Ve,4Sa,5Do,6Lu,7Ma,8Me,9Gi,0Ve,1Sa,2Do,3Lu,4Ma,5Me,6Gi,7Ve,8Sa,9Do,0Lu,1Ma,2Me,3Gi,4Ve,5Sa,6Do,7Lu,8Ma,9Me,0Gi,1Ve,Unnamed: 2
0,,Ore,,",30",",46",",50",,,",20",",48",",41",",07",",52",",11",,",53",",51",",14",",28",",33",,",32",",10",",03",",44",",39",",04",,",26",",15",",07",",11",",59",
1,,Ore,,,,,,",53",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

That, when loaded, results in this dataframe:

```py
>>> df
  Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1  1Me  2Gi  3Ve  4Sa  ...  7Lu  8Ma  9Me  0Gi  1Ve Unnamed: 2
0        NaN        Ore  NaN  ,30  ,46  ,50  ...  ,26  ,15  ,07  ,11  ,59        NaN
1        NaN        Ore  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN        NaN
```

And also, I have `values`, that is a numpy array of two lists.

```py
>>> values
array([list(['6,30', '5,46', '4,50', '5,20', '7,48', '5,41', '2,07', '3,52', '3,11', '4,53', '4,51', '5,14', '4,28', '3,33', '5,32', '3,10', '5,03', '4,44', '4,39', '5,04', '5,26', '7,15', '5,07', '6,11', '2,59']),
       list(['2,53'])], dtype=object)
```

My question is, I want to replace all elements in Dataframe that match a specific regex to be replaced with the corresponding element of the `values` list.

I assume that `df` and `values` have the same length (in this case 2) and also that "wrong" numbers to be replaced inside df are the same of the corresponding row in the `values` array.

In my case, I tried using `df.replace()`, but it didn't work; I got this error:

```py
>>> df_lattice2.replace(r"\d?,\d+", values)
TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'str'
```

After I while, I came out with an iterative algorithm, using `df.iterrows()`, counters and checking the elements one by one; I think, however, that a Pandas solution to a problem like this must exist, but I didn't find anything.

My expected output is:

```py
>>> expected_df
  Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1  1Me   2Gi   3Ve   4Sa  ...   7Lu   8Ma   9Me   0Gi   1Ve Unnamed: 2
0        NaN        Ore  NaN  6,30  5,46  4,50  ...  5,26  7,15  5,07  6,11  2,59        NaN
1        NaN        Ore  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN        NaN
```

A precondition is that any function should work row-to-row (so no `applymap`) because some values are found in the second row - and the corresponding value in the first row is `NaN` -, while `applymap` works column by column.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that number of strings in each row that matches the pattern is equal to corresponding length of lists in `values`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma yes; N lists = N rows, N[i] elements for list i = N[i] elements that match this pattern in row i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple pandas solution

```
s = df.stack()
s[s.str.contains(r'\d?,\d+', na=False)] = np.hstack(values)
out = s.unstack().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

#### Explanation

- `stack` the dataframe to reshape. Note: Stacking operation also drops the `NaN` values by default.

```
>>> df.stack()

0  Unnamed: 1    Ore
   2Gi           ,30
   3Ve           ,46
   4Sa           ,50
   ...
   9Me           ,07
   0Gi           ,11
   1Ve           ,59
1  Unnamed: 1    Ore
   6Lu           ,53
dtype: object
```

- Match the regular expression pattern (`\d?,\d+`) against the stacked frame using `str.contains`, this essentially creates a boolean mask

```
>>> s.str.contains(r'\d?,\d+', na=False)

0  Unnamed: 1    False
   2Gi            True
   3Ve            True
   4Sa            True
   ...
   9Me            True
   0Gi            True
   1Ve            True
1  Unnamed: 1    False
   6Lu            True
dtype: bool
```

- Using `hstack` flatten the `values` then assign these values to the matched strings in the stacked frame

```
>>> s[s.str.contains(r'\d?,\d+', na=False)] = np.hstack(values)
>>> s

0  Unnamed: 1     Ore
   2Gi           6,30
   3Ve           5,46
   4Sa           4,50
   ...
   9Me           5,07
   0Gi           6,11
   1Ve           2,59
1  Unnamed: 1     Ore
   6Lu           2,53
dtype: object
```

- Now `unstack` to reshape back into a dataframe and `reindex` the columns

```
>>> s.unstack().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)

   Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1  1Me   2Gi   3Ve   4Sa  5Do   6Lu   7Ma   8Me   9Gi   0Ve   1Sa   2Do  3Lu   4Ma   5Me   6Gi   7Ve   8Sa  9Do   0Lu   1Ma   2Me   3Gi   4Ve   5Sa  6Do   7Lu   8Ma   9Me   0Gi   1Ve  Unnamed: 2
0         NaN        Ore  NaN  6,30  5,46  4,50  NaN   NaN  5,20  7,48  5,41  2,07  3,52  3,11  NaN  4,53  4,51  5,14  4,28  3,33  NaN  5,32  3,10  5,03  4,44  4,39  5,04  NaN  5,26  7,15  5,07  6,11  2,59         NaN
1         NaN        Ore  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  2,53   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with integers in df, but strings everywhere else, so that's part of the problem.  Trying to replace with regex requires strings, so trying it with your df of digits will fail.  Also, trying to replace using the entire values array doesn't seem like what you want to do.  Iterrows is very slow, so avoid that at all costs.

Looks like you want to find the string '30' and replace with '6,30' for example.  You can do that with df.replace(), all at once, as you originally wanted.  You can also use replace on integers, e.g., replace the integer 30 with '6,30' in whatever data format that is.  I'm not sure how what the exact data is you are working with and what data types you want in the end, so see this toy example for replacing all matching values in a df at once:

```
row1list = ['30', '46', '50', '20']
row2list = ['48', '41', '07', '52']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list], columns=['1Me', '2Gi', '3ve', '4sa'])

values = ['6,30', '5,46', '2,07', '3,52']

for val in values:
    left, right = val.split(',')
    df = df.replace(right, val)

print(df)
#     1Me   2Gi   3ve   4sa
# 0  6,30  5,46    50    20
# 1    48    41  2,07  3,52
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but the problem is that I can have duplicates in the df (also on the same row). What I wanted to do is: I know that there are N elements that match this pattern, I know that in the first list (that matches the first row of df) there are N elements, so I want to "override" the values in df with the values of the list, row by row - first row with first list, second row with second list, and so on.